# transmitted getUserMedia / MediaRecorder video format larger than requested format. How to tell?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, h.264, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

Background:

On Windows 10 I'm using [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) (gUM) and [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)  in Google Chrome (v71) to capture and encode a video stream.

- I'm using the constraints parameter to gUM to tell it I want a video format of 352x288.
- I'm requesting `video/webm; codecs="avc1.42E01E"` as the MIME type of the encoded stream (that's H.264 boxed in [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/technical/whatis/index.html)).
- I'm selecting a cheezy webcam built into a laptop as the video source. It's called "EasyCamera" made by DMAX-AVC. It's tempting to call it CheezyCamera.

The video stream gets generated just fine.

Problem:

The dimensions of the encoded video in the stream are **440x360** rather than my requested **352x288**. This information is embedded in the recorded stream, and only visible from the consumer of that data. Use of the various APIs reveals the gUM stream, MediaRecorder, and `<video>` element metadata all think the dimensions are the ones I asked for.

Of course, webcam, gUM, and MediaRecorder treat the constraints parameter as suggestions, and are free to respond with something different. In this case they respond with 440x360 when I request 352x288. This system functions as designed; that is not my problem.

To clarify, the unexpected 440x360 dimensions are only visible to the consumer of the recorded stream. I hope to find a way to know the producer-side webcam, gUM, and MediaEncoder signal chain is producing a different resolution than I requested.

How does the stream consumer know the stream dimensions? They're in the 'PixelWidth' and 'PixelHeight' Matroska boxes, and they're baked in to the H.264 stream.  (Oddly enough, considering this is a software-chosen resolution, it isn't an integral number of 16x16 macroblocks. It still works of course.)

I can't parse the recorded data in the browser because it's stored in opaque blobs.

When I use a different, better, webcam (a Logitech C615) my encoded video stream is the size I requested.

My question:

Is there any way in the webcam / gUM / MediaRecorder / `<video>` signal chain to find the **actual dimensions of the encoded stream** in the browser actually recording the stream?  That is, can I find the signal chain's **response** to my **requested** dimensions without decoding the generated stream?

Comment: There are some contradictions in your sayings: Somewhere you say the *"The dimensions of the encoded video **in the stream** are 440x360"*, and then you say that all the Stream, the MediaRecorder and the video element (i.e the stream consumers) say it's the one you asked for (352x288). Are you sure you didn't meant to say it's only the recorded file that has the wrong dimensions? Also please clarify how you did check the dimensions from these consumers. And finally, did you try to reproduce from an other media stream having the same dimensions? E.g one coming from a canvas.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code, example how you set width and height for your encoder. If I remember correctly from my last project, `getUserMedia()` example does not guarantee that video size will be the exactly what you request for and depends on your hardware as well.

Comment: Please see my edits to my question. Working on the `<canvas>` source...

Comment: "Oddly enough this generated resolution isn't an integral number of 16x16 macroblocks" - that's normal and not an issue, it gets padded to the nearest multiple and the decoder crops it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried the various things offered by other answerers of this question, I have not succeeded in solving this problem.

I conclude it's a bug somewhere in the signal chain webcam to Google Chrome to gUM.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MediaStream.getVideoTracks()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream#Methods) method to get the video track ([MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack)), then use [`MediaStreamTrack.getSettings()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack#Methods) to get [MediaTrackSettings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings) object, which contains the height and width of the video of the stream.

So if I request a video of 0 height specified as Constraints, I get a video of height 1 pixels. While streaming we can retrieve both the height I requested and the height I am getting as output.

```
function handleMediaStream(mystream){
  let videoStreamTrack = mystream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  let constraints = videoStreamTrack.getConstraints();
  console.log(constraints.width, constraints.height);
  // outputs: 640 0
  let settings = videoStreamTrack.getSettings();
  console.log(settings.width, settings.height);
  // outputs: 640 1
}

let videoConstraints = { width: 640, height: 0 }
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: videoConstraints })
.then(function create_media_recorder(mystream) {
  handleMediaStream(mystream);
});
```

Comment: Sadly the MediaStreamTrack getSettings result (and getCapabilities and getConstraints results)  show the width and height I requested, not the actual width and height.

Comment: Are you sure about the actual width and height? How are you getting the height and width?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the `exact` constraint keyword like in [this test](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/webrtc/webrtc_getusermedia_browsertest.cc?type=cs&q=getusermedia+exact&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=431)

```
const sdPalConstraints = {
  video: {width: {exact: 352}, height: {exact: 288}}
};
// Assuming |video| exists and represents a <video> element.
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(sdPalConstraints)
                      .then(stream) => {video.srcObject = stream};
```

This is no guarantee that the WebCam will be streaming in that resolution, but if the produced one differs from the requested, [VideoTrackAdapter](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/renderer/media/stream/video_track_adapter.h?&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=24) will be engaged to adapt it for you (and for MediaRecorder).

Comment: I wish I could say this helped. But it didn't. Sigh.